# Import contacts from GAL to users accounts in Office 365

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

my organization move to Office 365 and users should have all GAL contacts on their folder contacts and phones. I try to use [a Steve](https://www.allabout365.com/2010/07/using-powershell-to-import-contacts-into-exchange-and-outlook-live/)!

But I've got:

> Exception calling "AutodiscoverUrl" with "1" argument(s): "Autodiscover blocked a potentially insecure redirection to h
>   ttps://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml. To allow Autodiscover to follow the redirection, use t
>   he AutodiscoverUrl(string, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback) overload."
>   At C:\PS\Import-MailboxContacts.ps1:159 char:9
>   +         $service.AutodiscoverUrl($EmailAddress);
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AutodiscoverLocalException

Any ideas how I can add contacts?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking or what you are doing to get that error.  For example, I'm guessing that you used a Power Shell script of some kind because of your tag, but I have no idea of the topology of your environment, nor which server (or type/role) you ran a script against, nor what the script you ran is.

Answer (score 0):

In that script you reference you need to change the line

```
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($EmailAddress);
```

to

```
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})
```

This will essentially allow redirection of Autodiscover you need for Office365